# How do I show IBus indicator?

Tags: 11.04, indicator, ibus

How to show IBus indicator in Ubuntu 11.04? It disappears.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using Ubuntu 10.10 or 11.04, the notification area has been disabled by default. This was made to favor Ubuntu indicators. There is a tutorial showing how to enable the notification area back on [WebUpd8.org](http://webupd8.org/2011/04/how-to-re-enable-notification-area.html).

Nonetheless, if you use Ubuntu 11.10 or upper, then there is a new feature that is able to convert many of the notification icons into neat indicators. This is automatic. So iBus in Ubuntu 11.10 appears normally in the upper bar of your desktop.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, and this might help you. On my pc the ibus icon (little keyboard) is at the bottom right corner of my screen ant not in the tray anymore. It's very hard to see because it's transparent. If I click on it, I can choose the input method.

Comment: I found the solution: http://www.webupd8.org/2011/04/how-to-re-enable-notification-area.html

Comment: @Nguyen Can you post that separately as an answer so we can vote on it?